# Where is the memusage command in Ubuntu?

Tags: memory-usage

On my Ubuntu LTS system, I have a [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/memusage.1.html) for memusage:

```
$ man memusage
MEMUSAGE(1)                                      Linux user manual                                      MEMUSAGE(1)

NAME
       memusage - profile memory usage of a program
...
```

Yet, when I try to run memusage, it is not found.

And searching of occurrences on my system yields this:

```
$ dpkg -S memusage
libc6-i386: /lib32/libmemusage.so
manpages: /usr/share/man/man1/memusage.1.gz
libc6-dbg:amd64: /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so
libc6:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so
libreoffice-script-provider-bsh: /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/Scripts/beanshell/MemoryUsage/memusage.bsh
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so
manpages: /usr/share/man/man1/memusagestat.1.gz
```

Why is there a manual page for memusage, but not the command itself?

Is it maybe something that is for 32-bit Ubuntu only, and not 64-bit Ubuntu?

Note: that gmemusage (as suggested by Ubuntu) is a totally different thing.

PS: Any alternatives that let's me find allocation hot-spots in my program? I'm trying to see where all my memory is going in my code.

**OS:** Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: I think this may answer your question? ["How do I use “memusage” commmand for check Memory usage of Particular program"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459558/how-do-i-use-memusage-commmand-for-check-memory-usage-of-particular-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memusage` is available in the `libc-devtools` package [since version 2.31-8](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1210957/accepted-glibc-231-8-source-amd64-into-experimental-experimental/). This is available in Ubuntu 21.04 and later, Debian 11 and later, and derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

This script is not included into the binary package, but exists in the [source code form](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/tree/malloc/memusage.sh?h=ubuntu/bionic-security).

To compile it from the source code use:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudi apt-get build-dep libc6

cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source libc6
cd glibc-2.27/
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
```

Then go to *malloc* directory and try to find the script here:

```
cd malloc
ls memusage*
```

Optionally move it to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get build-dep libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'glibc' as source package instead of 'libc6'
E: Unable to find a source package for libc6
`

Comment: Then you have to enable source code repositories from Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) first.